# create a stripe token in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a stripe token using GAS. my code is below

```
  function createToken(){
  var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens";
  
  var payload = {
  "Card": { 
  "Number" : "4242424242424242",
  "Exp_month" : "10",
  "Exp_year": "2021",
  "Cvc": "314",
  }
  };
  
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = {    
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sk_test_4eC***7dc:")
    };
    
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(res.getContentText())
  }
```

But I keep getting the following error, what am I missing?

[20-10-22 12:39:19:452 EDT] Exception: Request failed for https://api.stripe.com returned code 400.

Truncated server response: {
"error": {
"code": "parameter_missing",
"doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
"message": "You must su... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
at createToken(Code:43:27)

Comment: You're likely running into this error because the properties that you're passing as the request payload are capitalized. The should all be lowercase as shown in the examples here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card. Bear in mind though that this approach for tokenizing credit card details is not very secure and opens you up to PCI regulations. I'd recommend reading this guide here for more on that: https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide

Comment: I changed that and now I'm getting the following error: Exception: Request failed for https://api.stripe.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: { "error": { "message": "You must pass full card details to create a token.", "type": "invalid_request_error" } } (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 43, file "Code")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw [the official document](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card), the sample curl command is as follows/

```
$ curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
  -u sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc: \
  -d "card[number]"=4242424242424242 \
  -d "card[exp_month]"=10 \
  -d "card[exp_year]"=2021 \
  -d "card[cvc]"=314
```

When above sample curl is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script (Google Apps Script):

```
var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens";
var params = {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc:")
  },
  payload: {
    "card[number]": "4242424242424242",
    "card[exp_month]": "10",
    "card[exp_year]": "2021",
    "card[cvc]": "314"
  }
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
console.log(res.getContentText())
```

#### Note:

- From [OP's replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486833/create-a-stripe-token-in-google-apps-script/64491320?noredirect=1#comment114037136_64491320), each values are required to be the string type.

#### References:

- [Create a card token (official document)](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: hi @tanaike thanks! it worked but needed one more correction. The values also need apostrophes like this  `"card[number]": "4242424242424242",` edit the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @jack Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I could confirm that it was required to be the string type for each value. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?